# How to add WordPress theme dir to the beginning of each img src w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress-theming

Basically, I am lazy and I just want jQuery to update my image URLs for me in my WordPress theme. On WordPress, normally you have to do this:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/ect.png" alt="" />
```

But what I'm trying to do in jQuery is to get it to dynamically replace

```
<img src="images
```

with

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/
```

I want it to automatically determine the blog URL, I don't want to have to set it manually if that makes sense. Should be easy for someone well versed in WP.

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you just use a proper IDE and use a feature called "replace in files" , it will be harder to do it with jquery than just press a few buttons .

Comment: notepad++ would be enough for this task!

Comment: That's not the point of what I'm trying to do though, I could easily replace each URL and add the template tag in front of them, but this is something I've been thinking about trying as sort of a little "wordpress hack" I could blog about.

Comment: pick another topic to blog about, *wordpress hacks* should be useful! and if you insist...put a link back to this answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@comment:

```
$('img').hide();

$('img').each(function(index){
  $(this).attr('src', 'http://your-url'+$(this).attr('src')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

You can use any number, 1000 for instance, instead of `'slow'` ( `'slow'` means 600 mSeconds long )

```
$(this).attr('src', 'http://your-url'+$(this).attr('src')).fadeIn(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('img').each(function(index){
  $(this).attr('src', 'http://your-url'+$(this).attr('src'));
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/
http://api.jquery.com/each/

Note that jQuery runs **on client**, so if you are going to insert php code, it will be not executed. However, you can pass `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` to the script, inside 'http://your-url'.

Comment: That works great, I had a similar code I was using but this one is much shorter. Only one complaint about that, when I load the page it displays blank images (like the link is dead), and then once the page is fully loaded it displays the images. Is there any way to hide them and maybe get them to fade in when they're loaded?